# NSString into NSMutableData without conversion to NSData

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring, nsdata, gksession

my problem is the following. I would like to encapsulate a NSString in a NSMutableData object. But I would like to do it together with other items and without first encapsulating it into a NSData. It's only bytes after all isn't it?

My final NSMutableData object would look something like

```
[header | stringLength | NSString]
```

where `header` is a char and `stringLength` is an unsigned short.
I build my packet like this

```
unsigned short stringLength = myString.length;
NSMutableData* nData = [NSMutableData dataWithBytes:(const void*)&header length:sizeof(char)];
[nData appendBytes:(const void*)&dataLength length:sizeof(unsigned short)];
[nData appendBytes:(const void*)myString length:stringLength];
```

I would then send this over a gkSession and at the other end I would extract the sting lenght and then the string itself:

```
NSString* temp = [NSString alloc];
[data getBytes:(void*)&temp range:NSMakeRange(sizeof(char)+sizeof(unsigned short), stringLenght)];
```

For some reasons this is giving me bad memory access. I suspect that `myString.length` is not doing exactly what I would expect. Do you have any hints? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is incorrect:

```
[nData appendBytes:(const void*)myString length:stringLength];
```

This is encoding the first part of the underlying `NSString` structure (which is larger than `stringLength`).

What you mean is:

```
[nData appendBytes:[myString UTF8String] 
            length:[myString lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

`length` is the number of characters. This can be substantially smaller than the number of bytes for multibyte characters.

Just as a side note: if you can shorten your length to 1 byte (0-255), then that encoding is called a Pascal String, and `CFString` can handle that encoding natively (see `CFStringGetPascalString()`). Not something you generally want to do, but interesting. It's particularly nice with `CFStringCreateWithPascalStringNoCopy()`, since you can avoid the memory copy operation entirely. This is mostly for legacy support, and I wouldn't jump through any hoops to use it, but sometimes it's handy.

Comment: Thanks Rob! My next question at this point would be: how can I safely unpack the string? I packed it as a UTF8String, but I get an abort signal on the other side when I simply do `[data getBytes:(void*)tmpString range:NSMakeRange(rangeBegin, rangeLength)];`. I declared `tmpString` as `NSMutableString* tmpString = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:rangeLength];`. Is it maybe because of the encoding? What kind of encoding does `tmpString` expect to be filled with?

Comment: I think I found the way: first dump everything in a generic buffer and then get the original string back using '[[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:(const void*)buffer length:dL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];'. Thanks again for your help!